# jQuery ajax Form Submit - how to?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

```
<div class="full_popup">
<section class="left_sec">
    <div class="img_holder">
        <form action="do_up.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="upload">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file"> //input file
    </div>
</section>
<section class="right_sec">
<div class="body">
```

> Details  Inputs

```
<ul class="details">
    <li class="loc"><input type="text" id="geo" placeholder="place photo taked in"></li>
    <li class="disc"><textarea placeholder="Discription" id="disc"></textarea></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <button class="popup_post" type="submit">Post</button> //submit
    </form>  //ending form
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

I use jquery form plugin

and here it is how i initialize form

```
$('#upload').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit()
});
```

The problem is when I submit this form it doesn't take all values from inputs 
and when I put inputs directly after form tag it takes all.

So how can I do that with inputs inside different divs?

Comment: You might need name attributes on the fields that you intend to submit e.g. <input type="text" id="geo" name="geo" placeholder="place photo taked in">

Comment: What is the plugin "ajaxSubmit" ? can you supply a link... as it's not a core function

Comment: I don´t know why you try to submit the same form twice? `.submit` is as far as I know an event which listens on fired submit button. And also as far as I know `.ajaxSubmit` sends it again as an XHR call.

Comment: @alpham8 OP can simply call `return false` or `event.preventDefault()`, as noted in the plugin's API: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<form>` element is spanning multiple elements and it's not being closed properly. The browser will *attempt* to fix your HTML by closing the `<form>` element prematurely:

```
<section class="left_sec">
    <div class="img_holder">
        <form action="do_up.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="upload">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        </form><!-- likely to be inserted by the browser to fix lack of closing tag -->
    </div>
</section>
```

You should wrap ALL your inputs with a single `<form>` element instead, i.e. by moving `<form>` several levels up your DOM tree so that all inputs whose values you want to submit are wrapped in within.

In other words:

```
<form action="do_up.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="upload">
    <div class="full_popup">
        <section class="left_sec">
            <div class="img_holder">
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="right_sec">                   
            <div class="body">
                <ul class="details">
                    <li class="loc"><input type="text" id="geo" placeholder="place photo taked in" /></li>     
                    <li class="disc"><textarea placeholder="Discription" id="disc"></textarea></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <button class="popup_post" type="submit">Post</button>      
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also, since `.ajaxSubmit()` (from the jQuery plugin [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)) will replace the default submit actions, you should [prevent default submission action from being followed through](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api):

```
$('#upload').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit()
    return false;
});
```

...or...

```
$('#upload').submit(function(e) { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit()
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

p/s: You should use `<!-- ... -->` not `//` to escape comments in HTML.